# Use of anonymous function with feval

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I do not understand the anonymous function in the following code:

```
x = 0.25 * randn(3, 1);
y = 0.25 * randn(3, 1);
h = 0.1*randn(3, 1);

interpolate = @(x, y, h, x_new, y_new) ...
    feval(@(int) int(x_new, y_new), ...
          TriScatteredInterp([-1; -1; 1; 1; x], ...
                             [-1; 1; -1; 1; y], ...
                             [0; 0; 0; 0; h]));
```

I have some understanding about anonymous functions and the `feval` function, but I searched the matlab docs and do not find an example using several @ signs. Also the `feval` parameter have anonymous function.

Can anyone give some hints about this?

Comment: Did you read http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?

Comment: i am not very clear about the feval use @fucntion as its parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've probably worked out that this is creating a anonymous function with the handle `interpolate`:

`interpolate = @(x, y, h, x_new, y_new)...`

`interpolate` takes those five inputs, and calls `feval`.  Now here it gets a bit tricky, because `feval` itself contains another anonymous function.

`@(int) int(x_new, y_new)`, means, take input `int` and return the output of `int(x_new,y_new)`.  The additional input to `feval`, in this case `TriScatteredInterp`, is taken as the input to that anonymous function.  This is **not** a reference to a built-in function `int` (as might be the case if you saw something starting `feval(@int...`).

So what `interpolate` does is basically equivalent to doing this, for any given set of inputs:

```
tsi =  TriScatteredInterp([-1; -1; 1; 1; x], ...
                             [-1; 1; -1; 1; y], ...
                             [0; 0; 0; 0; h]));

tsi(x_new,y_new)
```

You can test this by comparing the output of `tsi(x_new,y_new)` with the output of `interpolate(x, y, h, x_new, y_new)`.

Comment: @(int) int(x_new, y_new) part, i am still a little confused. i saw the anonymous function doc and see this style" sqr = @(x) x.^2;", so  here @(int) int(x_new, y_new), the first "int" should be a parameter, the latter "int" should be sometype operation. BUt cleayly here it is not. how is the thing?

Comment: The two `int` references are the same.The operation being performed is returning the output of `int(x_new,y_new)`, for any `int` (`int` could be a 2D matrix, function that takes two values , etc). Anonymous functions are flexible like this. If you write `f = @(x) x(5)`, then `f(@ones)` and `f(y)` will both work. The first calls the function `ones(5)`, the second returns the 5th value of the variable `y`.

Comment: i have a question that the TriScattedInterp's effect? how the TriScattedInterp set up a function rule upon   "(x,y) to h" rule? here.